# Connecting a private slot to a QAction in QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt

In the next code ,i am trying to add action to the contextMenuEvent for a QGraphicsItem

but the problem is the slot "resize()" is never called

```
void Rect::contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    QMenu * menu = new QMenu();
      QAction *resizeAction = menu->addAction("Resize?");
      connect(resizeAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(resize()));
      menu->exec(event->screenPos());
      delete menu;

}
```

Edit::
The header file of class "Rect"

```
 class Rect:  public QObject,public QGraphicsItem
    {

    public:
        enum { Type = UserType + 4 };
        Rect(int x,int y,QString s,QColor myRectangleColor,
             QGraphicsItem *parent = 0, QGraphicsScene *scene = 0);
        Rect();
        int type() const
        { return Type; }
        QPainterPath shape() const;
        QRectF my_rect;

        virtual QRectF boundingRect() const; 
        virtual void paint (QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);

    protected:

        virtual void mouseMoveEvent ( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event )
        virtual void mousePressEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event );
        virtual void mouseReleaseEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event );

        virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
        virtual void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
        virtual bool sceneEventFilter ( QGraphicsItem * watched, QEvent * event ) ;
        virtual void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event);


    private:
        private slots:
        void resize();
        void MoveUpFun();
    };
```

Comment: `QGraphicsItem` is not a `QObject`. But you have successfully compiled this code, does it mean that `Rect` inherits both `QGraphicsItem` and `QObject`? Please show header file contents. Check return value of `connect`.

Comment: connect returns a bool. Check it to know if its being connected. If its private it surely not ...

Comment: @Riateche yes it inherits both classes and "connect" returns false

Comment: `connect` returning false means you're getting a nice warning on your console telling you why connect() is failing. Given that your `connect` compiles, and `triggered` is indeed a QAction's signal, my guess is that `resize` method is not a slot (either because it's not marked as slot, or because the whole class isn't being processed by `moc` because it lacks `Q_OBJECT`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And I was right in my comment: you're missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class.

Comment: A small macro you must put in your QObject derived classes to enable signals and slots for them (... and other stuff too, but that's not relevant here). Preventing further questions: you need to add your header to the `HEADERS` section in your .pro file and *re-run* qmake. See [the QObject documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) for more info.